# How to update post's featured image in front-end

Tags: front-end

I created a new template page with code to allow front-end posting. Everything works great, with tags, post meta and image uploading (as featured image).

I have seen many codes about front-end post editing, but even though I tried to figure it out I can not successfully make it to work.

I took as example this [How can I edit a post from the frontend?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/how-can-i-edit-a-post-from-the-frontend/18781#18781) and placed it in single.php with no luck. I guess the right way to have it, is to have an EDIT link below the post and there will be appear a new php template that contains the edit form when it is clicked. Is this correct?

Secondly, how can I update the featured image I added from the front-end ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin allows you to change post thumbnails (featured images).

Comment: I installed it in Roots theme that I am using for developing purposes and changed it to twenty eleven for this to work. However is a great modern tool and does what it says. Please tell me why this didn't work with Roots and how to make it work with a template that may be not working ?

Comment: If you actually add the [code that displays thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Default_Usage), Front-end Editor works fine.

Comment: It was there from the beginning.

Comment: Well, I don't know. Like I said, it worked for me.