# Link submission website (ala Reddit)?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, links

[Pligg](http://pligg.com/) sucks, [Hotaru CMS](http://hotarucms.org/) is dead and I'm not sure if the [Nominate](http://prothemedesign.com/themes/nominate-for-wordpress/) theme is what I want. Basically I'm trying to create a link submission website like Reddit with WordPress, this would basically mean:

- Voting
- Easy link submission
- Member creation and restriction of groups
- oEmbed support (optional)

I looked at [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) but it appears it's trying to be more of a social networking site (Facebook) instead of a social link submission site (Reddit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These can be nicely done with WordPress using custom post type for link submission, so then the rest becomes very easy using a few plugins:

- Voting - [CMS Vote Up Social CMS
  News](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-vote-up-social-cms-news-button/) will handle the voting.
- Easy link submission - simple custom front end post form would do the job (ex: [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/i-am-trying-to-create-a-simple-frontend-form-for-posting/15288#15288) or you can use plugins like Mini TDO, Gravity forms...
- Member creation and restriction of
  groups -  this is build in with WordPress, [users and roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)
- oEmbed support -  here is the only part i can think of that you would have a lot of work with unless you mean giving users ability to oEmbed there links like youtube in which case you can use the built in [oEmbed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) support.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Bainternet :) How would one create a system that users can create their own groups?

Comment: Probably using custom taxonomies, if you mean groups of links, and User_meta if you mean groups of users.