# Tag selector like stackexchange?

Tags: plugins, tags, select

I'm creating my own form based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/i-am-trying-to-create-a-simple-frontend-form-for-posting/15288#15288) and I'd like to have a tag selector which is similar to the one on StackExchange. I can roll my own but I was wondering if something similar already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that using [**JQuery autocomplete plugin**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Example)

and once you have included all of the needed JS files just add this code after your new post form

```
$terms = get_terms("post_tag");
$tags = '';
$count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){ 
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       $tags .=  '"'.$term->name.'", '; 
    }
    $tags = substr($tags,0,-2);
 }

echo ' <script>
JQuery("#post_tags").autocomplete(['.$tags.'], {
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: true,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: ", ",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300
    });
</script>';
```

**note:** Now this is good if you only have a small number of tags, but if you have hundreds or thousands of tags then using an ajax solution is a must.

Comment: Could you expand on "once you've included all the JS libraries" a bit more please? I'm actually trying to create my first plugin that is a tag search form, and it should function exactly like the jquery autocomplete demo (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) with multipe comma delimited values. Although I can get this to work fine in a standalone application, it doesn't work in a plugin. I'm not sure what library files or how they should be included in the plugin. Using WP 3.9

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code for the tag box in `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` and the function `tagBox` in `wp-admin/js/post.js`. You may adapt or reuse these functions.

Comment: Dear toscho, what is the actual equivalent of 'post.dev.js' in 'wp-admin/js/'? I dont find this file in WP 3.5+. Thanks

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces It is just `post.js` now.